How to instantiate specific beans conditionally based on a java program argument?
Title: How to instantiate specific beans conditionally based on a Spring Boot property?

Problem:
I have a service class in my Spring Boot application that needs to instantiate different components (or beans) based on a configured property, such as mode.
Here is the current structure of my service class:
@Service
public class EngineService {

    private final EngineArguments engineArguments;
    private final EngineConfig engineConfig;

    public EngineService(EngineArguments engineArguments, EngineConfig engineConfig) {
        this.engineArguments = engineArguments;
        this.engineConfig = engineConfig;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void execute() {
        if ("MODE_A".equals(engineArguments.getMode())) {
            ModeAEngine modeAEngine = ModeAEngineInitializer.createEngine(engineArguments, engineConfig);
            modeAEngine.execute();
        } else if ("MODE_B".equals(engineArguments.getMode())) {
            ModeBEngine modeBEngine = ModeBEngineInitializer.createEngine(engineArguments, engineConfig);
            modeBEngine.execute();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No valid engine found!");
        }
    }
}

The ModeAEngineInitializer and ModeBEngineInitializer classes return instances of ModeAEngine or ModeBEngine, respectively.

The Issue:
The initialization of these components involves multiple instantiations using new, as shown below. These dependencies rely on shared objects EngineArguments and EngineConfig.
ModeAEngineInitializer.java
public class ModeAEngineInitializer {

    public static ModeAEngine createEngine(EngineArguments engineArguments, EngineConfig engineConfig) {
        DependencyA dependencyA = new DependencyA(engineArguments);
        DependencyB dependencyB = new DependencyB(engineConfig);
        HelperService helperService = new HelperService(dependencyA, dependencyB);
        
        return new ModeAEngine(dependencyA, helperService);
    }
}

ModeBEngineInitializer.java
public class ModeBEngineInitializer {

    public static ModeBEngine createEngine(EngineArguments engineArguments, EngineConfig engineConfig) {
        DependencyX dependencyX = new DependencyX(engineArguments);
        DependencyY dependencyY = new DependencyY(engineConfig);
        ProcessorService processorService = new ProcessorService(dependencyX, dependencyY);
        
        return new ModeBEngine(dependencyX, processorService);
    }
}


The Final Problem:
Currently, the ModeAEngineInitializer and ModeBEngineInitializer classes contain multiple instantiations using new. I want to replace these with Spring beans so that only the necessary dependencies and engines are instantiated based on the value of a property mode.
For example:

If mode=MODE_A, then only ModeAEngine and its dependencies should be created.
If mode=MODE_B, then only ModeBEngine and its dependencies should be created.


Right now I just have a class that is responsible of fetching the argument --engine and detect wether it should run ModeA or ModeB.
Yet when I look at all the "new" calls, I'm guessing that I should be able to do it with Conditional. Which I did in the past. Yet when doing so I couldn't inject my object that contains the argument --engine inside the condition checker.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-conditional-annotations
So I tried to do it with properties, but when looking inside the context object, no engine value was found. I logged the context object.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-conditionalonproperty
How can I configure Spring Boot to instantiate specific beans conditionally based on the value of an argument ?

Now if there would be an @ConditionalOnProperty annotation that you could place on an @Bean method to conditionally instantiate beans. You can even place it on an @Configuration class, create 2 both for a different mode and just 1 will be active.

I am not sure if i understood, Do you want drive your engine by parameter passed to your main function not a property? or your annotation @ConditionalOnProperty didn't work?

With the @ConditionalOnProperty should I be able to compare it to an arg ? because I don't want to put it in a file, or do a system env variable.

Assuming that we are executing this application with program arguments --engine=Mode_A|Mode_B below is one approach we can use to conditionally instantiate beans based on the value passed to the engine program argument.
@Configuration
public class EngineBeanConfiguration {

    static class ConditionalOnEngineMode implements Condition {

        @Override
        public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
            Map<String, Object> annotationAttributes = metadata.getAnnotationAttributes(EngineMode.class.getName());
            String engineModeExpectedForBean = ((EngineMode.EngineModeTypes) annotationAttributes.get("engineMode")).name();
            return context.getEnvironment().getRequiredProperty("engine").equalsIgnoreCase(engineModeExpectedForBean);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    @EngineMode(engineMode = EngineMode.EngineModeTypes.MODE_A)
    @Conditional(value = ConditionalOnEngineMode.class)
    public ModeAEngine modeAEngine () {
        return new ModeAEngine();
    }

    @Bean
    @EngineMode(engineMode = EngineMode.EngineModeTypes.MODE_B)
    @Conditional(value = ConditionalOnEngineMode.class)
    public ModeBEngine modeBEngine () {
        return new ModeBEngine();
    }
}

Below is the annotation to specify the engine mode used by the conditional
@Target(value = ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface EngineMode {

    EngineModeTypes engineMode();

    enum EngineModeTypes {
        MODE_A, MODE_B
    }
}

Spring boot does add the program arguments to the Environment where it can be fetched from and to know more on this we can look here
Hope this helps.
